# Warhammer 40k: Dawn of War II: Chaos Rising expansion: Infinite mission play possible?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

In Dawn of War II, before the end of the game, you're able to go on any number of side missions to finish leveling up your squad and get shiny new gear rewards and drops from the enemies.

However, in the expansion, it's very linear and the amount of missions seems static. I'd love to be able to go back and get all the really cool items for my squad members and mess around with corruption levels, but there doesn't appear to be any random missions once you complete a certain number of them and reach the final one.

Is there an "infinite play" in the expansion like in the base game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. Even when you have a choice of missions, they are limited in time.

In my opinion, they chose to make missions with more identity, at the cost of this "infinity". Dawn of War 2 missions allowed to play an infinite amount of missions... But they were always the same: "go to the other side to kill the boss" or "defend the place". I think missions in Chaos Rising are more "unique", and more interesting.

However, since your choices in Chaos Rising have an influence on the game, it makes it interesting to play the whole campaign again, only to play it differently. So there you can find a part of "infinity".

Comment: I understand the limited in time aspect, just wasn't sure about the "kill the boss" "defend the place" or "destroy x target" missions ala the DoW2 baseline game. I was ok with that because I loved getting my troops completely decked out. Oh well.

Comment: @JN - yes, I understand your point, I agree with it, I like also to have unlimited side missions. However, the expansion is nicely done in the way that you don't really have the need to "grind" the experience for your troops.